# Number Pyramid Nested Loop in java

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm wondering if you could help me out. I'm trying to write a nested for loop in java that displays a number pyramid that looks like;

```
            1
          2 1
        4 2 1
      8 4 2 1
   16 8 4 2 1
32 16 8 4 2 1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
 int n = 32;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i *= 2) {
            for (int k = 1; k <= i; k *= 2) {
                System.out.print(k + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

How do i get the output to display correctly

Comment: What does your sample code output so far?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hRwfg3i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could revert one counter and add one `for` to care about the tabs:

```
    int n = 32;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i *= 2) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j *= 2)
            System.out.print("\t");
        for (int k = i; k >= 1; k /= 2)
            if (i == k)
                System.out.print(k);
            else
                System.out.print("\t" + k);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: i see, never thought of that, thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

First you need to calculate how many levels your pyramid needs. If I'm not mistaken this should be `ceil(log2(n)) + 1`. Afterwards you can loop through the levels and fill them. Also remember to print a new line after each level.

Answer (score 0):

While solving this "exercise" I encountered two problems.

1. You need to know how many lines you want to print. With this information you can calculate how many empty spaces you need infront of each row.
2. You need to know the number of digits the biggest number has. This is necessary to reserve enough space when printing each number. This is my result.

   ```
                   1
                2  1
             4  2  1
          8  4  2  1
      16  8  4  2  1
   32 16  8  4  2  1
   ```

Further I would start the program with the number of rows you want to have, instead of the biggest number. This seemed easier to me.